# Adobe Illustrator: problem with the brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Sorry for my English, I'm French, I'm going to put the translation.I use the Wacom tablet, with a sensitivity of 2000. When I draw at a percentage of 100-250%, my lines are perfect. But when I increase the size to 1000-2500% for small details, my features are a kind of break between each curve ... Yet my options of clarification are maximum. So, the trait would not be supposed to change. help me please.

(Francais) J'utilise la tablette Wacom, avec une sensibilité de 2000. Lorsque je dessine à un pourcentage de 100-250%, mes traits de lignes sont parfaite. Mais quand j'augmente la taille a 1000-2500% pour des petits détails, mes traits font une sorte de cassure entre chaques courbes... Pourtant, mes options de précisions sont aux maximum. Donc, le trait ne serait pas supposer changer. Aidez moi svp

Answer (score 2):

La traduction semble pauvre. 
<sub>The translation seems poor.</sub>

Je vais essayer, mais cette traduction peut aussi être médiocre.

<sub>Will attempt, but this translation may also be mediocre.</sub>

---

Les brosses ne sont pas conçues pour les petits détails. Surtout avec la tablette. Le plus que vous dessinez petit, plus vous rencontrerez de hoquet, trous, blobs et autres anomalies. Il n'y a pas grand chose à faire sauf travailler à une plus grande taille. Comme il s’agit d’un vecteur, l’art doit être facile à mettre à l’échelle.

<sub>Brushes are not designed for small details. Especially with the tablet. The smaller you draw, the more hiccups, holes, blobs, and other abnormalities you will encounter. There is not much to do except working at a bigger size. As it is a vector, the art must be easy to scale.</sub>

Vous trouverez peut-être mieux d'utiliser l'outil Plume pour les détails complexes.

<sub>You may find using the Pen Tool better for intricate detail.</sub>

---

J'espère qu'un francophone le lira et pourra vous aider davantage.

<sub>I hope a francophone will read it and can help you further.</sub>